# Having $_POST data within a PHP Class

Tags: php, post-redirect-get, correctness

I developed a habit of working like this in PHP and I was wondering if it is a correct way to work or not.

Basically, whenever I have a form, I would post the data to a 'handler' file which does a couple of basic checks (in certain cases) then creates an instance of the class.

The class __construct automatically calls a function within the class and begins validating the post data and redirects the user accordingly, along with a $_GET data to display a success message.

I'm aware this is the Post-Redirect-Get pattern, yet, my curiosity is: is it okay to redirect to a file and create the class instance within there, or is it okay if you post the data directly to the class file ?

Comment: i think that if you already check and validate with the $POST data you can POST them directly to your class file.

Comment: a class by itself does nothing. a file which contains only `<?php class foo {} ?>` is basically useless. you need to have some code that instantiates the object.

Comment: I obviously would have the code that instantinates the object, but within the file containing the class, I thought it's a bad habit to work with $_POST data within a class though. I was rather thinking I should pass everything via construct so class works with it's own variables.

Comment: Why is this question opinion based ? I guess there have to be some programming standards that have to be respected and rules that shouldn't be broken.

Comment: That would just mean more variables...which would actually make it more inefficient.